# How to do a Lua Patterns search correctly?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I am trying to do a pattern search, but it doesn't work. I have this code:

```
vars = "CmdTurn.on=off/GetPar.pwd=true"

_GET = {}
for k, v in string.gmatch(vars, "(%w+)(%p+)(%w+)=(%w+)&*") do
  _GET[k] = v
  print(k..":"..v)
end
```

After run this code I hope see this result:

```
CmdTurn.on:off
GetPar.pwd:true
```

But it doesn't work. The wrong result that appears is this one:

```
CmdTurn:.
GetPar:.
```

Any one could help me?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your problem is your using brackets to capture 4 items in the pattern, but only using 2 return variables (k and v). Try using variables a,b,c,d and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple capture groups in the pattern `(%w+)(%p+)(%w+)=(%w+)&*`, so `k` and `v` gets the result of the first two captures, which is not what you want.

Try this:

```
for k, v in string.gmatch(vars, "(%w+%p+%w+)=(%w+&*)") do
  print(k..":"..v)
end
```